# Is this an issue of angular's scope?

Tags: angularjs

### footer.js if defined as the main app.

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('footer', []);

app.directive('siteFooter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'site-footer.html',
    };
  });
})();
```

### footer.js if added as a dependency.

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('footer', []);

app.directive('siteFooter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'Hexdra/partials/site-footer.html',
    };
  });
})();
```

I have an app that controls just the footer of my site, I then inject that footer app into the main app that defines my page.

I use the `templateUrl` to load a template for the footer.

For the first case I'm confused because the `footer`app is not in the same directory as the template it's linked to, and it's still able to find it.

---

For the second case when the template has to be defined as '`Hexdra/partials/site-footer.html'`, why does it require me to go to the root?

If my files are structured as

```
 - Hexdra
 - -> app - contains the angular.Js files
 - -> assets 
 - -> partials - contains my site-footer.html file. 
 - html-files
```

wouldn't I need to use `'partials/site-footer.html'`?

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it.

Comment: The format has been changed to aid answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First I'm confused because the footerapp is not in the same directory
>   as the template its linked to, and it is still able to find it

That's a javascript feature.

> Second, for the second case when the template has to be defines as
>   'Hexdra/partials/site-footer.html', why does it require me to go to
>   the root?

The template is loaded with respect to the directory for index.html as the root, because the template is references by your script and your script files are loaded from index.html.

As a stand alone app, your script is loaded from the footer template and hence the root is the directory of the footer template.

Comment: What JavaScript feature is used?

Comment: You can reference any script anywhere and the root within the script reference wise remains the folder of the file that included the script.

Comment: Where your scripts live, their location, is irrelevant. Once included it is as if the html file contained the script itself

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something in your question?

Comment: So if the html file that called the footer script was inside the app folder then the root would be stuck to only files located in the app folder without redefining the templateUrl explicitly like i did in the second case?

Comment: I wouldn't call it stuck per se. Because you can navigate up in the folder tree.

Comment: If I can navigate up the folder tree, then whats the point of limiting my file scope?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107880/discussion-between-wilmer-s-and-drew-ackerman).